# How to crop borders/white spaces from image?

Tags: command-line, imagemagick, image-processing, batch

I have a lot of images which have white borders around them. I would like to crop those borders all at once, preferably from command line. I believe that it can be done with ImageMagick, but I couldn't find suitable command.

I know that it can be done with Windows program named Irfanview with "Auto crop borders" option, but I am looking for Ubuntu-based and preferably command line based solution.

Comment: Have you tried Gimp?

Comment: @Mitch No, I didn't know that Gimp does have batch mode. Anyway, using ImageMagick Trim is simpler, so I will stay with that solution.

Comment: [The dupe](https://askubuntu.com/questions/97695/is-there-a-lightweight-tool-to-crop-images-quickly) generally suggest GUI solutions...

Answer (score 118, accepted):

#### [ImageMagick Trim](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#trim)

The command line option `trim` used together with `convert`, or `mogrify` lets you trim borders of the same color as the corners of an image.

Usage:

```
convert input.png -trim output.png
```

The additional option `-fuzz` (which takes a percentage as an argument, e.g. `-fuzz 10%`) also removes colors near the corner colors.

**Note:** The `-fuzz` option must precede `-trim` because options' order matters for `convert` command to work as expected.

Use the option `+repage` to remove a canvas (if applicable).

#### ImageMagick Batch Trim (find)

Above command for ImageMagick Trim can also be used to batch process images combined with the `find` command:

```
find ./ -name "pattern" -exec convert {} -trim outputfolder/{} \;
```

The above command will trim all images that fit the `pattern` part of the command and save them in a new folder named `outputfolder`.

Assuming that images are PNGs, then command will look like this:

```
find ./ -name "*.png" -exec convert {} -trim outputfolder/{} \;
```

#### ImageMagick Batch Trim (mogrify)

While `find` allows for much greater control where output files will be placed, it is also possible to do the same with ImageMagick's `mogrify`:

```
mogrify -trim *.png
```

And if you want to crop colors near the corner colors (adjust the percentage based on the results you are observing):

```
mogrify -trim -fuzz 10% *.png
```

Please note that unlike `convert` and batch operation with `find` and `convert`, **`mogrify` overwrites all files**. To keep the originals use the `-path` option or **do a backup copy** of all images in the directory before proceeding with the `mogrify` command.

Side note: `mogrify` can be used to execute most (if not all) `convert` operations in batch, while overwriting original files.

As [Trevor noted in the comments](https://askubuntu.com/questions/351767/how-to-crop-borders-white-spaces-from-image/351772#comment2053617_351772), you can use the `-path` option to output converted files to a new directory without overwriting the original files:

```
mogrify -trim -path trimmed_folder/ *.png
```

#### IrfanView

IrfanView runs [quite nicely with Wine](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=163). Be sure to check the output of Irfanview carefully, as it sometimes breaks images when used with Wine.

Comment: It works. Thank you very much. I have added information about batch processing images with ImageMagick when combined ``find`` command as it was missing from your answer.

Comment: I used `mogrify -trim *.jpg` to crop all images in the current folder.

Comment: This is great. It saved me a lot of time.  TX :)

Comment: @ButtleButkus I edited the answer to include that information. For some reason I forgot about this  option earlier.

Comment: is there any way to trim a png image along its height, keeping the width fixed?

Comment: I think it's noteworthy that mogrify will *modify* the existing files (rather than creating new copies as pdfcrop would do). After all, you might loose "data"...

Comment: Well, I wasn't reading the entire post, but just the comments. I was hence referring to Buttle Butkus' comment. And since I was sure that others might do that, too, I wanted to add that note close to it, too.

Comment: the trim find command gives me this output:
convert: WriteBlob Failed `outputfolder/.//outputfolder/filename.png' @ error/png.c/MagickPNGErrorHandler/1715.

Comment: Regardless of the above error output, the trimmed images are actually there. Tried to get it to trim top and bottom only, ended up giving up and using Photoshop... (almost got it working, just kept adding white lines down the middle whenever i 'batched' the command):

Comment: @00-BBB: for a scriptable method to trim only one side see http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/crop/#trim_oneside

Comment: Note that if you don't want to overwrite the original files, you can use `mogrify` with the `-path` option: `mogrify -trim -path trimmed_folder/ *.png`

Comment: @wxyz: thank you - included a note on this in my  answer.