# Pinta selection cropping

Tags: pinta

I've just installed Pinta to basically crop a screenshot (why doesn't Ubuntu come with a simple image editing tool?!) but for the life of me cannot work out how to crop an image to a selection properly.  What I'm doing is using the rectangle selection tool, selecting the area I want to crop to then pressing 'Crop to Selection'.

The image crops, but it's not cropped the selection I made.  If I make the selection quite small, Pinta throws an exception.

Am I doing this simple task wrong?  Or is this a bug?

Comment: Seems a bug. Free ;-) advice: use `shutter` for this task http://shutter-project.org/

Comment: `gThumb` did the trick for me. Check [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/97700/16555)

Comment: I had a similar use-case but went with shotwell as it supports rotating and cropping.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem. Upgrading Pinta to a newer version today solved it for me.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install pinta
```

Comment: Downvote: Which version solves this issue? I have pinta@1.6 and am unable to find the cropping option.

Comment: @k0pernikus It's been a long time since I've been in Linux world, but looking at the Pinta home page, the project looks dead - the latest release looks to have been only a few weeks after my post in 2015.  Could be worth looking into an alternative app!

Edit: Just seen your comment above - looks like you found your alternative :)