# Cropping Images using Command Line Tools Only

Tags: command-line, image-processing

I want to crop an image using **command line tools only** indicating pixels to crop for the four directions (the same way we can crop in LibreOffice)

For example:

```
crop image.jpg -top 5px -bottom 7px -right 14px -left 3px
```

Is there such a tool (not GUI)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a lightweight tool to crop images quickly?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/97695/is-there-a-lightweight-tool-to-crop-images-quickly)

Comment: @ThomasWeller this is asking for command line and not GUI tool plus the linked question you supplied is about GUI so please just read the question again

Comment: The linked question does not specify the tool type. The second answer is about a command line tool: imagemagick. I know there are discussions on SO whether a question is a duplicate in case the answer is the same. People may agree or disagree.

Comment: @ThomasWeller but the answer is not convenient, moreover it doesn't show how and why he used the options.. Frankly did you understand the options used?! I myself can't get that information, it's just the first answer here, it's with no explanation which makes the answer low quality

Comment: Probably not a perfect answer there, but the rest should just be good portion of RTM.

Comment: @The rest are GUI tools

Answer (score 81):

Here is a workaround using `convert` from image magick pack.

```
sudo apt-get install imagemagick
```

For a picture `image.jpg`

```
$ identify image.jpg 

image.jpg JPEG 720x482 720x482+0+0 8-bit DirectClass 100KB 0.000u 0:00.009
```

As shown above, the input image is 720x482px.

Now to do cropping you have to determine two factors:

1. starting point of the cropping (includes 2 directions)
2. The cropped rectangle size (Here you can include the other directions)

Now back to the image `image.jpg` above, I want to crop:

- top 5px
- bottom 7px
- right 14px
- left 3px

then you could do it with (`width`x`height`+`left`+`top` / `w`x`h`+`l`+`t` format):

```
convert image.jpg -crop 703x470+3+5 output.jpg
```

Now

```
$ identify output.jpg 

output.jpg JPEG 703x470 703x470+0+0 8-bit DirectClass 102KB 0.000u 0:00.000
```

Comment: It's said that Imagemagick 7 uses the "magick" command in place of "convert". If anyone run into `command not found: convert` issue, try `magick`

Comment: This was a big help, but took me a while to wrap my head around the "calculations". I had a set of 1280x1024 images I needed to crop top and bottom from, so final image would have the "middle" 718 pixels from the original (taking off a black band top and bottom). I needed to use this: `convert in.png -crop 1280x718+0+152 out.png` where I understand that line to mean: `convert in.png -crop [final-right-x]x[final-right-y]+[crop-left]+[crop-top] out.png`, although that doesn't seem to match @Maythux's numbers... FWIW!

Comment: Shouldn't it be `703x470` instead of `713x470`? As the left+right cropping `= 3+14 = 17px`, that when subtracted from `720` is `703`, and not `713`.

Comment: This helped!
 I also suggested an edit to FIX both 703px instead of 713px (which I agree to), and inverted left and top in format `WxH+l+t`

Answer (score 31):

If you want to trim white regions away, `imagemagick` has a special command for it:

```
convert -trim input.jpg output.jpg
```

Comment: This is the equivalent of crop to content in gimp! Works great on pngs!

Comment: Use `mogrify -trim file.jpg` if you don't want to produce a copy of the original file.

Answer (score 16):

To create a "user friendly" cli- option, the script below can be used. Simply run the command:

```
<script> <image> <crop_left> <crop_right> <crop_top> <crop_bottom>
```

It creates a cropped image of `image.jpeg`, named `image[cropped].jpeg` in the same directory.

#### The script

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import subprocess
import sys

# image, crop- dimensions
img = sys.argv[1]; left = sys.argv[2]; right = sys.argv[3]; top = sys.argv[4]; bottom = sys.argv[5]
# arrange the output file's name and path
img_base = img[:img.rfind(".")]; extension = img[img.rfind("."):]; path = img[:img.rfind("/")]
img_out = img_base+"[cropped]"+extension
# get the current img' size
data = subprocess.check_output(["identify", img]).decode("utf-8").strip().replace(img, "")
size = [int(n) for n in data.replace(img, "").split()[1].split("x")]
# calculate the command to resize
w = str(size[0]-int(left)-int(right)); h = str(size[1]-int(top)-int(bottom)); x = left; y = top
# execute the command
cmd = ["convert", img, "-crop", w+"x"+h+"+"+x+"+"+y, "+repage", img_out]
subprocess.Popen(cmd)
```

#### How to use

1. The script uses `imagemagick`

   ```
   sudo apt-get install imagemagick
   ```
2. Save the script above as `crop_image` (no extension) in `~/bin`.
3. Create the directory if necessary. In that case, also run `source ~/.profile` to make the directory show up in `$PATH`.
4. Make the script executable.

Now simply run the script by its name, as mentioned, e.g.:

```
crop_image /path/to/image.jpg 20 30 40 50
```

Spaces are no problem, as long as in that case, you use quotes:

```
crop_image '/path/with spaces in the name/to/image.jpg' 20 30 40 50
```

Comment: @Maythux Not sure what your latest edit means, you mean the solution above does not work on your system? It is cli only.

Comment: I'm sorry I was off three days ago, so I don't know why you get a downvote, instead here my +1 since you deserve.

Comment: But I think even it works this would be pretty harder for a newbie a bit than using a native crop tool, but for me I love your way, pretty cool, sorry again for delay

Comment: Wow, thanks. The downvote I got because of this: http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/14082/how-much-data-does-the-system-need-to-detect-serial-down-votes

Comment: @Maythux while your answer is very well received :)

Answer (score 8):

The `crop` command needs 4 things. To understand it take the image you want to crop. Now, imagine that on the image, you are drawing a rectangle of the size which you want to retain. The area outside this rectangle will be eliminated, cropped. The rectangle must not be tilted i.e. the top side must be horizontal.

Now, note down these 4 things:

1. the width (W) in pixel of the rectangle
2. height (H) of the rectangle
3. distance of the left vertical side of the rectangle from the left margin/end (L) of the image
4. distance of the top side of the rectangle from the top margin/end of the image (T).

Thus you have now W, H, L and T values. So far so good. To know the pixels, you may install [krule](https://docs.kde.org/stable5/en/kdegraphics/kruler/introduction.html) tool in Ubuntu. Very useful.

Now, open the terminal and go to the folder where the image is stored. Use the following command and put the values of W, H, L and T properly:

```
convert input.jpg -crop WxH+L+T output.jpg
```

Comment: Not sure why this isn't the top answer. The whole reason I came here was to understand the encoding of the `-crop <geometry>` input, which everyone else just hand-waved over

Answer (score 5):

Use `mogrify -crop <W>x<H>+<X>+<Y> <files>`.

Careful: the files are **overwritten** without notice. Add the `-path` option to specify an output directory to prevent this if required.

As an example: `mogrify -crop 256x256+10+5 images/*.jpg` will crop each image in the `images` folder to a 256x256 image by starting 10 pixels from the top and 5 pixels from the side. It will overwrite the old images.

If you get a `Argument list too long` error due to trying to convert many images at once, simply wrap your image path in single quotes to prevent bash from expanding it: `mogrify -crop 256x256+10+5 'images/*.jpg'` (mogrify will do the expansion itself)

Answer (score 3):

You can use convert command in `image magick` pack.
To install `sudo apt-get install imagemagick` or `sudo yum install ImageMagick`.
Then use `-crop geometry` to crop the image. For more readings read [here](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/convert.php)

Comment: This crop by ratio and not with different margins

Comment: Nope, `-crop` option gives `x` and `y` That are offsets and `gravity`. so you can use it to time to crop a square

Comment: I posted it as answer, thanks for your help anyway, but you should write that in your answer before4

Comment: @Arronical Thanks I already get it and posted as answer. please check it