# How to crop a .ps image and output as .jpg on terminal

Tags: command-line, image-processing, convert, imagemagick, photoshop

I am trying to use imagemagick convert on Ubuntu to crop an image from a `.ps` file, and to make this cropped part as a separate image or `.png` or `.jpg`

I tried the following but it didn't work:

```
convert whatever.ps -crop 105x74mm+30+50 whenever.jpg
```

This only produced the same file.

I would like to know how can I use it on this file:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=15z5tE2c_7vvh7ShDv0oRw7rrG9NUpAO1

Answer (score 0):

I imagine you would have to first convert your ps file to jpg, and crop the jpg file after that first step is done.

For cropping, you can see [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/631695/698344). Basically, the command would be something like this:

`convert image.jpg -crop 713x470+5+3 output.jpg`