# How can you use Imagemagick crop to get first 100px from an image?

Tags: command-line, imagemagick, image-processing

It's been awhile since I've played with Imagemagick.  I do remember `crop` and I can take an image named `foo.png` and use:

```
convert foo.png -gravity north -crop 1000x100 bar.png
```

but my output is:

```
bar-0.png
bar-1.png
bar-2.png
bar-3.png
...
```

When I only want what's in `bar-0.png`.

I've researched around and found:

- [Cropping Images using Command Line Tools Only](https://askubuntu.com/questions/631689/cropping-images-using-command-line-tools-only)
- [Cropping images with ImageMagic produces wrong size images - why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39217722/cropping-images-with-imagemagic-produces-wrong-size-images-why)
- [How can I trim just the left and right side of an image using Imagemagick in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7854830/how-can-i-trim-just-the-left-and-right-side-of-an-image-using-imagemagick-in-php)
- [Cutting and Bordering](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/crop/)

What is the correct way to crop an image and just get the first return?  I'm not not worried about the aspect ratio or the size of the images.  I'm just trying to get a sample of the image's first 100px.

Answer (score 3):

You need to add the information from which X and Y you want to start, otherwise Imagemagick will repeat the crop:

```
convert foo.png -gravity north -crop 1000x100+0+0 bar.png
```